# Text Field Command (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, if-statement, text

I have a text field. When a certain text is in it, I want to run some code. But I'm confused on how to do this. Should I create an action for the text field, when the text is in it, and then create an `else if` with the name of the text field, and then the code I want when certain words are entered?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [UITextFieldDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate).

You could set the delegate of your textfield to a class that implement your custom actions in `textFieldDidEndEditing`.